# NO_PROXY ignored by .NET Core 3.0 on Windows

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, http-proxy, .net-core-3.0

We are trying to get proxy functionality to work in a .NET Core 3.0 (or 3.1) app on Windows. What we find is that the HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY variables are recognized and processed as expected, but the default proxy does not appear to honor the NO_PROXY variable. Here is sample code:

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 IWebProxy myProxy = HttpClient.DefaultProxy;
 Uri target = new Uri(args[0]);
 Uri proxy = myProxy.GetProxy(target);
 Console.WriteLine($"Target proxy for {target} is {proxy} {myProxy.IsBypassed(target)}");
```

If I run this from PowerShell as such:

```
if (-not $env:path.Contains('c:\data\src')) {
    $env:path = "$env:Path;C:\data\src\Local\DefaultProxy\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0"
}
$env:HTTPS_PROXY = 'http://10.11.10.10'
$env:NO_PROXY = '*'
DefaultProxy https://www.contoso.com
```

I get:

> Target proxy for https://www.contoso.com/ is http://10.11.10.10/ False

I expect to get blank and true.

What should I change so that I can use NO_PROXY to exclude domains from the default proxy?

Comment: context? https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29147 https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29371

Comment: Yes.  That post shows the intent of .Net Core 3.0 to support these variables.  I am trying to get it to work as I interpret the documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I pulled the code for System.Net.Http.HttpEnvironmentProxy [in .NET Core 3.1](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v3.1.0/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpEnvironmentProxy.cs) (and [in latest main development branch](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpEnvironmentProxy.cs)) and read through it, mainly through the IsMatchInBypassList method. There is no support for wildcards like asterisk (`*`) in NO_PROXY, hence this will not work at all. Also, the call to GetProxy completely ignores the NO_PROXY values.

To achieve the "wildcard" behavior, domains in the NO_PROXY list need to be prefixed with a dot (`.`), which is standard, but not particularly well documented. I can use this information to change my interpretation of the documentation and get better results.

So, if I modify the PowerShell code as follows:

```
$env:HTTPS_PROXY = 'http://10.11.10.10'
$env:NO_PROXY = '.contoso.com'
DefaultProxy https://www.contoso.com
```

Then I get:

> Target proxy for https://www.contoso.com/ is http://10.11.10.10/ True

Presumably the DefaultProxy logic will use the IsBypassed result of true to stop proxy on the NO_PROXY list.

Comment: I'd upvote this 1,000 times if I could!  Your finding in the ASP.NET Core HttpEnvironmentProxy code was the key to solving everything. Our default internal config used * (wildcard) in the NO_PROXY list. That turned out to be the source of why ASP.NET Core 3.1 and later was being mis-routing requests through proxy in spite of being listed in NO_PROXY. The `.EndsWith()` call on line 246 of `HttpEnvironmentProxy.cs` was the key to the whole mystery.

Comment: I believe this should be marked as accepted. Thanks for the research! I edited the answer to clarify a bit and added a link to the current code so that the answer stays relevant even beyond .NET Core 3.1. I summarized the changes in the edit's description.

Answer (score 1):

there is never a "standard" in the no_proxy. In Linux, most applications recognized it as lower_case. Sure, in Windows, it is always case-insensitive. But when it comes to wildcard matching or regex matching, there is no standard at all. Each application works its own way as it see fit, for no_proxy.