# How to set Default Proxy for "ApplicationPoolIdentity"?

Tags: iis, proxy, windows-server, iis-10, windows-server-2019

We are running a dotnet-core 3.1 MVC App on IIS 10. The app needs to connect to a local ressource without the proxy.

However our IT department provisions the VMs with Proxy configuration. For a local user I can simply remove the Proxy in IE Settings, Registry or netsh.

But the app running in an application pool under the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` keeps using a proxy and I am out of ideas where it is getting it from. As a workaround setting the ApplicationPoolIdentity to the my local user works.

What I tried so far:

1. Setting the `web.config` settings, but seems like [its not working for MVC](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27425#issuecomment-422912610)
2. Setting Environment variables in `web.config`:
   [image]
3. Setting the same Environment Variables via System Variables
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to **actively set the Proxy variables**, although you dont want to use them.

That's because .net core automatically [falls back to the user's proxy settings on windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultproxy?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).

So your `web.config` has to look like this:
[image]

Attention: Be sure to write your `NO_PROXY` variable without `*`  (`*.domain.de`) [as .net core does not know how to parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659954/no-proxy-ignored-by-net-core-3-0-on-windows/62663469#62663469). Just use `.domain.de`.